# Limit latest Mongoose records in ascending order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to get latest records in default (ascending) order.

This

```
Foo.find().sort({ created_at: -1}).limit(10);
```

works but results in descending order, which is not the desired behaviour.

Is `reverse()` the only way here? Can this be done with Mongoose alone somehow?

Comment: Doesn't `sort({ created_at: 1})...;` do what you're after?

Comment: @RunnyYolk It gets first 10 records, not latest, doesn't it?

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean. OK, I don't have any easy way to test this so apologies if I'm sending you on a wild goose chase, but could you do something like `Foo.find({ created_at: -1 }).limit(10).sort({ created_at: 1 });`?

Comment: @RunnyYolk Yes, that was the first thing I've tried. No luck.